# PHP cURL and Simple HTML Dom

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom, php-curl

I'm sorry, but I speak a little English only.

I use this:

```
<?php

function file_get_contents_curl ( $url ) {

    $ch = curl_init ();

    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 ); //
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 ); //
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0' ); // spoof

    $data = curl_exec ( $ch );

    curl_close ( $ch );

    return $data;

}

include ( __DIR__ . '/simplehtmldom_1_9_1/simple_html_dom.php' );

// 1. OK:     $url = 'https://www.p***hub.com/model/ashley-porner';
// 2. OK:     $url = 'https://www.p***hub.com/model/ashley-diamond-and-diamond-king';
// 3. NOT OK: $url = 'https://www.p***hub.com/model/ambercashh';
// 4. NOT OK: $url = 'https://www.p***hub.com/model/autumn-raine';

$html = file_get_contents_curl ( $url );
$html = str_get_html ( $html );

var_dump ( $html ); // boolean(false) if NOT OK

?>
```

The 1-2. URL is ok, but the 3-4. URL is not ok. Not show, no view. The return is false.

I try change from 600000 to 6000000 (~/simplehtmldom_1_9_1/simple_html_dom.php), but the new value is more loading time and than crashed my website:

```
// OLD: defined('MAX_FILE_SIZE') || define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 600000);
defined('MAX_FILE_SIZE') || define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 6000000); // NEW
```

What is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @soosdani29,
Can you please explain here what you want to do using this example?

Comment: I'm not sure those `*` are concealing much...

Comment: purely for research you understand I scripted up a test - it loaded all urls in under 3s and used less than 3.5Mb

Comment: I'm sorry, but not saved file and the old 600000 number is too little.

Comment: Your errors must lie elsewhere. I tested the above ( without `simple_html_dom.php` ) using same test procedure. It was slightly slower but used approximately the same memory - the peak memory used was 3.25Mb.

Comment: Why disable SSL verification? I think www.p***hub.com uses a valid certificate, not tested tho *cough*

Comment: @RamRaider LOL @ purely for research.

Answer (score 0):

As test you can run the following - obviously the urls will need editing but it shows reasonable performance - why you were running out of memory must therefore lie in code not included

```
<?php


    function file_get_contents_curl ( $url ) {
        $ch = curl_init ();
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0' ); // spoof
        $data = curl_exec ( $ch );
        curl_close ( $ch );
        return $data;
    }


    $start=time();
    $memstart=memory_get_usage();


    $baseurl='https://www.*******.com/model/';
    $models=['ashley-porner','ashley-diamond-and-diamond-king','ambercashh','autumn-raine'];


    libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
    $dom=new DOMDocument;
    $dom->validateOnParse=false;
    $dom->recover=true;
    $dom->strictErrorChecking=false;


    /* do some expensive DOM operations to test performance */
    $query='//section[ @class="topProfileHeader" ]/div/div/div[ @class="content-columns" ]/div[ @class="infoPiece" ]';


    foreach( $models as $model ){
        $url = $baseurl . $model;
        $res = file_get_contents_curl( $url );

        $dom->loadHTML( $res );
        $xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
        libxml_clear_errors();

        $col=$xp->query( $query );
        if( $col->length > 0 ){
            foreach( $col as $node ) {
                echo str_repeat( '.', strlen( $node->nodeValue ) ) . '<br />';
            }
        }
    }

    $memory=memory_get_usage() - $memstart;
    printf(
        '<div style="padding:1rem; border:1px solid red;">Script took approx: %ss - consumed: %sMb, Peak memory consumption: %sMb</div>', 
        ( time() - $start ), 
        round( $memory / pow(1024,2), 2 ), 
        round( memory_get_peak_usage() / pow(1024,2), 2 )
    );

?>
```

[image: The result...]

Comment: The @OPs code, not mine! I am aware of the implications

Comment: I am posting the same canned comment whenever I see this in use. You could warn them in your answer or I could do that in the comments underneath. I am not attacking you in any way and I am not going to down vote you for using this. This is just a warning for future readers.